# Import Private Key to keychain as non-extractable objective C OSX app

Tags: objective-c, macos, keychain, private-key

I have a shell script that imports a p12 to a User's keychain. For instance an example from the command line on OSX would be:

```
"security import /tmp/somecertificate.p12 -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain -P somepass -x "
```

The -x flag marks the private key as non exportable, and it works.

Is there a way to do this in objective C ? I am currently writing an OSX app, and want to do this natively with the Security Framework. I  have this code which works and imports the P12 to the keychain, but I can't figure out how to mark the private key as non-extractable. My objective C for p12 import is as follows:

```
NSString * password = @"somepassword";
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                   pathForResource:@"somecertificate" ofType:@"p12" inDirectory:@"/tmp"];

// prepare password
CFStringRef cfPassword = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL,
                                                   password.UTF8String,
                                                   kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
const void *keys[]   = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
const void *values[] = { cfPassword };
CFDictionaryRef optionsDictionary
= CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, keys, values, 1,
                     NULL, NULL);

// prepare p12 file content
NSData * fileContent = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
CFDataRef cfDataOfFileContent = (__bridge CFDataRef)fileContent;

// extract p12 file content into items (array)
CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
OSStatus status = errSecSuccess;
//import p12
status = SecPKCS12Import(cfDataOfFileContent,
                         optionsDictionary,
                         &items);
```

Thanks for any info you can provide.